# error while loading shared libraries: libboost_system.so.1.49.0

Tags: linux, bitcoin, bitcoind

When I try to run "bitcoin-cli" I get this error...

error while loading shared libraries: libboost_system.so.1.49.0

I did upgrade my Debian linux box to...

Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.2 (jessie)
Release:        8.2
Codename:       jessie

When I run apt-get install libbooost_system.1.49 it will not allow it since it is deprecated.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compile libboost 1.49, download the source from here: [Boost 1.49](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_49_0.html) uncompress and follow INSTALL file instructions, if you already have dependencies this should something as:

- ./configure
- make
- sudo make install

Then you can verify if that library requirement is satisfy by using `ldd /usr/bin/bitcoin-cli` assuming that you have it globally installed in that location.